# Is Visual Studio 2010 SP1 safe to install and what exactly is Assembly signing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, assemblies

I've just received [this MSDN blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx) in my rss reader and I would like to know (since I don't fully understand the process that he talking about if I should or should not install SP1

Furthermore I would like to know:

- how are assemblies signed in visual studio ?
- how the operating system checks these signs ?
- does the gcc (mingw) or any other compilers for Windows sign their assemblies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Yes. If you aren't delivering signed assemblies, then you don't have to worry about patching the MSBuild tools.

2) With a public key. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ab4eace3.aspx

3) The OS doesn't. The .Net Framework does. The assembly loader verifies the public key against a digest to detect modifications. If the assembly has been modified, it doesn't get loaded. http://www.csharp411.com/net-assembly-faq-part-3-strong-names-and-signing/

4) I have no idea. On Windows, the concept is something that exists in the .Net framework. Win32 binaries don't allow for that feature.